# Hibernate Interceptor.instantiate()

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

I am trying to use `org.hibernate.Interceptor.instantiate()` to intercept instantiations (obviously) and manually instantiate a particular object using a constructor other than the default. If one is to read into the JavaDoc for this method, this, in fact, appears to be the entire point of Hibernate exposing such a thing.

However, all I am given is the entity name, the `EntityMode`, and the `Serializable` identifier. So unless my goal was to call a constructor that takes as its only parameter the ID, I am SOL. Why does this method exist if it only gives me enough information to call *one* other (very specific) constructor? How am I supposed to retrieve the values of the other entity properties?

**Edit:** Apparently, after some more work and research, what I am trying to do is impossible. So I just accepted Mike's answer and called it a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instantiate interceptor is called to allow you to provide a customized mechanism for instantiating a new mapped entity prior to any of its properties being set.  Since this entity doesn't exist prior to the invocation of this interceptor there is no possibility that any of its properties could have been set.  The only values that Hibernate knows at this point in the life cycle are the type of the entity and the ID that it is going to be assigned.  You would use this interceptor to alter instance instantiation based on, for example, configuration settings, but not on property values that will be set after instantiation.

What are you attempting to accomplish with this?

Comment: I'm just trying to find some way around Hibernate's naive mandate that all your objects provide a default constructor for instantiation. It seems odd that a supposedly OO framework would violate one of the core tenets of OOP (encapsulation) by forcing you to provide public setters for all of your properties (I know; private setters; but it's the principle!). Reflection allows you to call any constructor you want (frameworks such as Spring do this), so their calling of `Class<T>.newInstance()` with no parameters is simply a design failure on their part, not some inherent limitation of Java.